# Access property from include inside a class method in PHP

Tags: php, class, scope

How do you make a class property available to the other included file inside the same class' method?

```
// file A.php
class A
{
    private $var = 1;

    public function go()
    {
        include('another.php');
    }
}
```

in another file:

```
// this is another.php file
// how can I access class A->var?
echo $var; // this can't be right
```

Is this possible given the scope. If var is an array then we can use extract but if var is not, we can wrap it in an array. **Is there a better way**?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

okay, to clarify **another.php** is literally another file. Basically, in the above examples, we have 2 files **A.php** which contains class A and **another.php** which is another file/script executing something.

**Answered: My bad... I included another.php from index.php.. I see scoping still applies.. thanks everyone..**

Comment: In short, just delete line 4 of index.php and it will work.... but that's why I don't recommend depending on this behavior: like I said in my answer, if you include another.php **anywhere else**, then you will get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question *seems* to be, "*when inside a file included from within a method, how do I access a private instance member?*"  Right?

In your example code, you're including a file inside a method.

Methods are just functions.  Like all other areas of PHP, the file that gets included will inherit *the entire current scope*.  That means that the include sees everything in scope in that method.  Including `$this`.

In other words, you'd access the property in the include file just like you'd access it from inside the function itself, as `$this->var`.

---

Example, using the PHP interactive shell:

```
[charles@lobotomy /tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php
echo $this->var, "\n";

[charles@lobotomy /tmp]$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > class Test2 { private $var; public function __construct($x) { $this->var = $x; } public function go() { include './test.php'; } }
php > $t = new Test2('Hello, world!');
php > $t->go();
Hello, world!
php > exit
[charles@lobotomy /tmp]$ php --version
PHP 5.4.4 (cli) (built: Jun 14 2012 18:31:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0rc1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: well, i just tried it and: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ****\another.php on line 3

Comment: What PHP version are you using?  I've provided a live example above to demonstrate how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `$var` as private, which means `$var` can **only** be accessed by member functions.  If you need to access `$var`, either make it public, or return it from a member function.  You should read more about visibility from the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

**Edit:** What makes your situation interesting is that you are calling `include` from a member function.  `include` will inherit the scope from which it is called.  So, technically, you can call `$this->var` from `another.php`.  However, I **strongly encourage against this practice**.  If `another.php` gets included anywhere else, you will get errors.  Please, *please* don't do this.  It's terrible programming practice.

If you really must, add these lines to `A.php`:

```
$obj = new A();
$obj->go();    // this will call another.php, which will echo "$this->var"
```

And then change `another.php` to this:

```
echo $this->var;
```

And it will work; you will get the right output.  Note that if you do not declare an instance of class A this will fail (eg, `A::go()`, `A->go()`, etc will all fail).  This is such a terrible way to go about things in PHP.

But doing things a better way, you could make the variable public:

```
class A {
    public $var = 1;  //note, it is public!
    public function go() {
        include('another.php');
    }
}
$obj = new A();
echo $obj->var; //woot!
```

Or, keep it private (which is better OOP):

```
class A {
    private $var = 1;  //note, it is private

    //make a public function that returns var:
    public function getVar() {
        return $this->var;
    }

    public function go() {
        include('another.php');
    }
}

$obj = new A();
echo $obj->getVar(); //woot!
```

Comment: i don't think making it public makes a difference since another.php is literally another file. not on the same file A.php so the scoping is not applicable.

Comment: @Jojo: yes, it does make a difference.  The location of the file is irrelevant to scope

Comment: @cegfault another.php is another file. It is executing on an instance of A specifically on its method go. another.php is literally another file. Basically, in the above examples, we have 2 files A.php which contains class A and another.php which is another file/script executing something.

Comment: @Jojo: what's important is **not** that it is another file, but that you are *including* that file from *within* a member function.  I've updated my answer to address that.

Comment: @cegfault this is what you're going to get when you do that: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ****\another.php... and please let's go away with bad programming practice. loading a template view is typically done on a method so bad programming practice totally depends on how it is being used.

Comment: @Jojo: You are probably getting that error by trying to access the function `go` generically, like `A::go`, etc.  To use `$this` you have to declare an instance of the class: `$obj = new A()` and then call `go` on that instance: `$obj->go()`

Comment: P.S. Using an include inside a member function that *depends* on being called from a member function because it needs to access private variables is indeed bad programming practice

Answer (score -2):

```
 class A
{
    public $var = 1;

    public function go()
    {
        include('another.php');
    }
}

$objA = new A();

$objA->go();
```

Comment: -1, you have provided code, but have explained nothing.  What is this?  How is it different from above?  What changes were made?  Why?

Comment: thanks for knowing me wat i have done wrong. i'll explain properly next time thanks ...